# Seahorse, PGP: What does the exported .pgp-file contain?

Tags: 13.04, seahorse, pgp

I created a pgp-key with Seahorse 3.6.3. If i select the key and go to "File -> Export", i can choose between two options: An .asc-file, which exports the public key in a text format, and a .pgp-file, which creates a binary file.

I can't figure out what the binary file contains and for what it is used. Does it contain my private key? Can i give it away (because i did without understanding what i was doing)? What is it for?

TIA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenPGP has two different file formats:

1. **binary** (more efficient in terms of storage and transmission).
2. **ascii armored** (better software compatibility).

Seahorse probably includes your public key, public subkeys, user ids and incoming signatures with your key (like GnuPG does). To verify what's included, run `gpg --list-packets [filename]`, which will dump all OpenPGP packets included in the file.